# Как разобраться в чужом коде php-сайта?

Tags: php

Есть файлы php, как отдельные части сайта. Где можно узнать, как, каким образом их соединить в единый сайт, если сам к написанию сайта отношения не имел? Подойдет все: книги, статьи и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Учите PHP по книжкам (а не по чужому коду), когда багаж знаний будет большим, то и само собой научитесь разбираться в чужом коде.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно смотреть конкретные php-скрипты. Если в них есть обращение к конкретному серверу (к тому, откуда стырили файл), то нужно заменить эти обращения на адрес своего сервера. Если скрипт работает "сам по себе", то можно просто закинуть его на FTP-сервер вашего сайта. Если скрипт использует какие-то ресурсы сервера, на котором находится (например, открывает картинку /images/image.png), то нужно найти или создать эти ресурсы и залить в соответствующую папку (т.е., в данном примере, создать в каталоге с php-скриптом каталог images и в него залить image.png), но это опять смотреть сам скрипт. Если скрипт связан с другими скриптами с этого сайта, то их тоже нужно скачать и залить на свой сервер. И, конечно же, нужно просмотреть все скрипты и изменить конкретные данные (например, имя сайта, копирайт, и т.п.).
Ну а вообще, что бы "разобраться в чужом коде" (т.е. понимать, что и как этот код делает), нужно для начала знать язык этого кода, в данном случае PHP.

Comment: >изменить конкретные данные (например, копирайт).

Сильно :D . Это уже статья! http://www.ukru.ru/code/07/146/

Answer (score 0):

Обычно включал отображение ошибок, в том числе, notice и все их исправлял. Подходит для простых и средних движков, как правило, само<s>пальных</s>писных. По сложным(типа IPB, drupal) обычно имеется документация.

Используйте продвинутые IDE, они помогут сообразить где чего и откуда берется.

Ищите точки выхода и от них осторожно "раскручивайте" в обратную сторону. Обращайте внимания на конструкции типа 
`$$varname`....
`$funcname()`....
`compact()`....
`list()`....
`global`....
`__get()/__set()`....
Они могут существенно усложнить жизнь.

Ну, да, требуется знание PHP, этого не отнимешь. =)